# $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 1$ in disc with radius $1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation, linear-pde

> Consider the inhomogeneous elliptic equation $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 1$
>   (this is often called a Poisson equation) in the disc $x^2 + y^2 < 1$,
>   with the boundary condition $u = a$ on the boundary $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ of
>   the disc. Find the solution $u$, noting that $u$ will be a function of
>   $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

I know that there will be a homogenous and a particular solution.

I think that the homogenous solution directly follows Poisson's Formula

$$u(r,\theta ) = \frac{(a^2 - r^2)}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{h(\theta )}{a^2 - 2 \arccos(\theta - \phi ) + r^2} \, \mathrm d \theta$$

where, in this case, $h(\theta ) = a$. I'm pretty sure that $a=1$ in this case but can someone confirm?

But then I have no idea how to solve for the particular solution.

Comment: In polar coordinates, the 2d-Laplace operator has the form

$$\Delta f = f_{xx} + f_{yy} = \frac1r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2}$$
For a particular solution of $u$, you just need to solve an ODE

$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{du}{dr}\right) = 1$$

Comment: sorry my ODE skills are rusty. How would I solve this ODE?

Answer (score 1):

Both the inhomogeneous function and the boundary condition are radially symmetric, so it's sufficient to find a solution $u(r)$ such that

\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{r}(ru_r)_r = 1 \\
u(1) = a
\end{cases}

Find the general solution by inverting each operation

\begin{align}
(ru_r)_r &= r \\
ru_r &= \frac{r^2}{2} + c_1 \\
u_r &= \frac{r}{2} + \frac{c_1}{r} \\
u &= \frac{r^2}{4} + c_1\ln r + c_2
\end{align}

$u(0)$ needs to be finite, so $c_1 = 0$, and the boundary condition $u(1)=a$ gives $ c_2 = a - \frac14 $.

Hence, the final solution is

$$ u(r) = \frac{r^2-1}{4} + a $$